# how can ı activate mps for yolov8

Tags: pytorch, yolov8, mps, macbookpro

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")
model.to("mps")
results = model.train(data='data/datas.yaml',
conf=0.3,
epochs=3,device=‘mps’)
```

I am trying to train a model on my Yolov8 model, but even if I try for example 3 epochs, the training time takes hours. I installed the Nightly version and the normal version, but it does not work.
I also tried this but it doesn't work **torch.backends.mps.is_available()**
version:macos sonoma

Comment: It can be helpful for others to understand the problem if you describe why exactly you perceive the steps you have taken are not working.

Comment: While model train is running, it shows gpu=0 and it takes long minutes to run even for 3 epochs